# Material Autocomplete Input showing displaying [Object object] despite using displayWith property

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using an input with mat-autocomplete for choosing an option of list of objects (they have ID, name, surname, etc.). I need the formControl's value to be all the object and not only the name, so I can display name + surname, and then use the ID for something else. I have no problems when searching through the input and selecting one option, it is displayed as I want and I can save the whole selected object.

**Issue:** When I want to set the value through the code - I'm using the same form for creating and editing, so sometimes I have to set the control's value with the current value. But when I do that it is showing as [Object object] and I don't know why, or whether is it possible to do what I want to?

I have this code in my template:

```
<input matInput type="text" formControlName="padre" placeholder="Ingrese el {{rolPadre}} asociado" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required />
<mat-autocomplete #auto [displayWith]="displayPadre">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let padre of possiblePadres | async" [value]="padre">
    {{padre.nombre}} {{padre.apellido}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

And this is the display Fn:

```
displayPadre(padre: Usuario): string {
  return padre ? `${padre.nombre} ${padre.apellido}` : undefined;
}
```

And the problem happens when I want to do something like this:

```
this.padre.setValue(exampleObject);
```

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: What is the thing you want to display in option? only name or all values?

Comment: Currently I'm displaying two properties (name + surname) both in the possible options and in the input when you select one, but saving all the object in the formControl value. If I set programmatically the value of the control, it displays [Object object] instead of name + surname as in the display function

Comment: Your form control holds just one item? Should it hold more of them?
I'm asking this because you're using `mat-autocomplete`, and that component is usually used when you have to hold in your form control multiple items

Comment: @BogdanChereghi I use mat-autocomplete to show the possible options when choosing the item called 'padre'. I have a list of possible options Then off course, the form control value is just one when you choose. When I'm editing an existing user instead of creating one, the complete form comes filled, and I want to show in that input the current value, but it can be changed for another possible option.

Comment: @JoséMedrano Well, if you're selecting just one why don't you use `mat-select` ?

If you want to implement a `mat-select` you'll need provide the `compareWith` function to the `mat-select`.

You can read more here https://material.angular.io/components/select/api.

If you need help just tell and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yes, it was a possibility but needed an autocomplete to make it easier to the user, because there could be a lot of possible options to choose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with the way you set your input value. Your input is like:

```
<input formControlName="padre">
```

And you're trying to set value with:

```
this.padre.setValue({});
```

But if you have a form controller like `this.padre`, then you should bind it like:

```
<input [formControl]="padre">
```

instead of using `formControlName="padre"`.

[Run it on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ldhaq2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)

Comment: @JoséMedrano No problem, happy coding :)